# Please explain "Invalid BXL stream"

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures

I'm trying to develop a stored procedure that does machine language prediction.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_prediction_xgb_classify;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE get_prediction_xgb_classify (@my_text varchar(100))
AS  
BEGIN
DECLARE @my_script nvarchar(4000)
SET @my_script = '

import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib

predictors = "" + "' + @my_text + '"
fields = predictors.strip().split(",")
n_fields = len(fields)

clf = joblib.load("C:/sm/trained_models/xgb_classify.pkl")
print("clf:\n", clf)
row = np.array(predictors.split(","),dtype=float).reshape(1,5)
print(" row: ", row)

predicted = clf.predict(row)[0]
#print(" predicted: ", predicted)

#probabilities = clf.predict_proba(row)[0]
#probability = probabilities[predicted]
#print("predicted: ", predicted, ", probabilities: ", probabilities, ", probability: ", probability)

'
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',   
@script = @my_script
END
GO

EXEC get_prediction_xgb_classify "0.215, -0.499, 1.654, 4.25, 1.559"
GO
```

This code crashes at the line:

```
predicted = clf.predict(row)[0]
```

with the message: Invalid BXL stream

If I comment out the predict line I get:

```
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
clf:
 XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=1,
       max_depth=19, min_child_weight=1.0, missing=nan, n_estimators=1000,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=7,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=16.524663677130047,
       seed=None, silent=True, subsample=0.844367185738714)
 row:  [[ 0.215 -0.499  1.654  4.25   1.559]]
```

I also put this code in Visual Studio 2017 and un-commented all the print statements. It ran o.k. and gave good results.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: It looks it is related  to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684941/invalid-bxl-stream-in-ms-sql-server-while-executing-r-scripts

Comment: This link suggested that the SQL Server 2017 python was out of date. I opened a cmd shell and positioned it over S:\SQL_Server_2017\MSSQL14.HEDGETOOLS\PYTHON_SERVICES\Scripts>. I then entered: "conda update --all" and almost 100 packages were upgraded,  The "Invalid BXL Stream" message went away, but now I cannot import packages like sklearn.  What a mess.