# pandas concat giving invalid BXL error sql server 2017

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sql-server-2017

While I am trying to concat two dataframe in **sql server 2017**. 
It is showing the error. While the same code is working good in independent jupyter-notebook.

Please help me out with the solution. Memory solution, up gradation of package not working out.

Code below:

'''python

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_PyForecast]
    @inputquery nvarchar(max)  
  AS
  BEGIN
       EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'Python',
  @script=N'OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels as sm

data = InputDataSet[["Date", "Consumption"]]
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%b %d %Y %H:%M%p")
data["Date"] = data["Date"].dt.date
data = data.set_index("Date")

ts = data.copy()
train = ts[:85]
test = ts[85:]

y_hat_avg = test.copy()
fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(np.asarray(train["Consumption"]) ,seasonal_periods=12 ,trend="add", seasonal="add").fit()
y_hat_avg["Fitted"] = fit1.forecast(len(test))

foreIndex = pd.date_range(start="2018/4/1", periods=12, freq="M")
fore = pd.DataFrame(index = foreIndex)

fore["Forecasted"] = fit1.forecast(len(fore))

frame = [train, y_hat_avg, fore]
result_final = pd.concat(frame)

result_final.reset_index(inplace=True)
result_final.rename(columns={"index":"DateTime"}, inplace=True)
OutputDataSet = result_final
  ',
```

'''

`To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.`

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass `'sort=True'`.

```
  result_final = pd.concat(frame)
``'
Invalid BXL stream
```

Comment: To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False' this is a warning not an error

Comment: "Invalid BXL stream" is the error raising from this line only.

Comment: @GpandaM, can you share some more code - it is very hard to get an understanding ion what is going wrong from what you have shared.

Comment: @NielsBerglund updated, please check

Comment: I checked  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684941/invalid-bxl-stream-in-ms-sql-server-while-executing-r-scripts 
But this is not working

Comment: The data is not so big

Comment: @GpandaM Print out each datatype from your OutputDataSet. I suspect you have some weird datatypes in there.